# check to see if key exist in 2 dictionary in same line

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 dictionary:

```
a = {'abc': 12}
b = {'abcd': 13, 'abc': 99}
```

I want to check if a certain key exist in both the dictionary. In this case i want to check if both a and c contain the key 'abc'

I have the following code:

```
if 'abc' in a:
    if 'abc' in b:
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
else:
    print(False)
```

and:

```
if ('abc' in a) and ('abc' in b):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope - that's pretty much as good as it gets... It's readable and obvious as to what's happening:

If the number of `dict`s grows:

```
all('abc' in d for d in (d1, d2, d3, d4))
```

Or, just pre-compute first, and access that:

```
common_keys = set(d1).intersection(d2, d2, d3, d4)
'abc' in common_keys
```

Comment: The second has a negative performance hit, I think. If 'abc' is not present in `a`, there is no sense to deal with `b`. In my opinion this intersection is premature. You have lost benefits of lazy evaluation this way.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Depends how frequent the operation is, and if `d1` is always the "primary" dict...

Answer (score 3):

One liner :)

```
print ('abc' in a) and ('abc' in b)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> 'abc' in (a.viewkeys() & b.viewkeys())
True
```

Comment: For *one* key membership check this is actually overkill. If `a` and `b` are large, this incurs a O(M) (where M is the smallest key count) cost, while the key membership test itself would be O(1). Better just do `'abc' in a and 'abc' in b`, much simpler and faster.

Comment: If you are going to do a lot of these tests, then it may well be an advantage to use dict views, but for this simple case you are wasting CPU cycles here.

Comment: If 'abc' is not present in `a`, there is no sense to deal with `b`. In my opinion this intersection is premature. You have lost benefits of lazy evaluation this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think that solution:

```
if ('abc' in a) and ('abc' in b):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

is the best and most pythonic way to do it.

Comment: In Python 2.x, `a.keys() + b.keys()` will just concatenate two lists together which isn't going to work correctly for the `'abr' in` check

Comment: I don't get what would go wrong, except the fact that it may have duplicated values...

Comment: Say: `k1 = [1]` and `k2 = [2]`, then `k1 + k2` is `[1, 2]` - So, if we're looking to see if `1` *is in **both*** then `1 in k3` is true, even though it's not in both.... The concatenation will only ever tell if you if it's in *either* of the dicts...

Comment: @zmo; what if `a` has the key and `b` doesn't? If you add the keys together it will always be true, whereas the desired result would be false.

Comment: right, shit happens :-) removed wrong answer. thanks for pointing this out. (I don't get why from time to time I can tell such stupid things... whereas that's the kind of mistakes I never do in real code).

Comment: @zmo no problem - in Python 3.x, `a.keys() & b.keys()` would have been okay though ;)

Answer (score 0):

What about generalizing to N dictionaries using list comprehension:

```
a = {'abc': 12}
b = {'abcd': 13, 'abc': 99}
c = {'abcd': 13, 'abc': 99, 'xyz': 1}
key = 'abc'

if any([key in d.keys() for d in [a,b,c]]):
  print('key found in at least one dict')
elif all([key in d.keys() for d in [a,b,c]]):
  print('key found in all dicts')
```

It took me a while to learn to like list comprehensions, but they are really just one line 'for-loops' and very fast too.